# Is the generalized entropy of certain events alway null?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, entropy, divergence

In their paper: [Novel Decompositions of Proper Scoring Rules for Classification](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/73982233.pdf),  Kull and Flach wrote in section *2.2 Divergence, Entropy and Properness* that when $y$ is the true class $d(p,y)=\phi(p,y)$ the divergence is equal to the proper scoring rule.

However, I have a hard time finding it to be true. Indeed, let say that in a classification problem with $K$ class the true class is the vector $y=(y_{1}, \cdots, y_{K})$ with $y_{i}=1$ and $y_{j}=0$ for all $j \neq i$,  we have:
$$\begin{align*}
d(p,y) &= s(p,y)-s(y,y)\\
       &= \sum_{j=1}^{K} \phi(p, e_{j})y_{j} - \sum_{j=1}^{k} \phi(y, e_{j})y_{j}\\
       &= \sum_{j=1}^{K} (\phi(p, e_{j}) - \phi(y, e_{j}))y_{j} \\
       &= \phi(p, e_{i}) - \phi(y, e_{i}) \\
\end{align*}$$
Here $y = e_{i}$, so we can clearly see that for the statement to be correct, the entropy of certain event must be equal to 0.
But it is really the case ? While it is true for the scoring rule considered in the paper, i.e the log loss and the Brier score. It is not true for the sperical score for instance.

Indeed, the generalized entropy function related to the sperical score is
$$
e(p) = (\sum_{i=1}^{K} p_{i}^{\alpha})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}
$$
We can clearly see that $e(y)=1$ in this case.

Furthermore all the decomposition in the paper are based on the statement that $d(p,y)=\phi(p,y)$.
Am I missing something here ? Or is the assumption that the decompositions hold for strictly proper scoring rules with null generalized entropy for certain events should be made ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that $d(p,e_i)=\phi(p,e_i)-\phi(e_i,e_i)$ and therefore, $d(p,e_i)=\phi(p,e_i)$ only holds for those proper scoring rules for which $\phi(e_i,e_i)=0$. Thus, the last 2 sentences at the end of section 2.2 in the paper "Novel Decompositions of Proper Scoring Rules for Classification" are misleading and I apologise for that. However, all the decompositions in the paper have been stated about $\mathbb{E}[d(S,Y)]$ and are correct.

You can easily adapt the decompositions from the paper to all proper scoring rules, including those for which $\phi(e_i,e_i)\neq 0$. Notice first that following the notation of the paper:
$$\mathbb{E}[d(S,Y)]=\mathbb{E}[s(S,Y)-s(Y,Y)]=\mathbb{E}[\phi(S,Y)-\phi(Y,Y)]=\mathbb{E}[\phi(S,Y)]-\mathbb{E}[\phi(Y,Y)]$$
Therefore, for any proper scoring rule you can write:
$$\mathbb{E}[\phi(S,Y)]=\mathbb{E}[\phi(Y,Y)]+\mathbb{E}[d(S,Y)]$$
You can now decompose $\mathbb{E}[d(S,Y)]$ using any decomposition from the paper. For example:
$$\mathbb{E}[\phi(S,Y)]=\mathbb{E}[\phi(Y,Y)]+\mathbb{E}[d(S,C)]+\mathbb{E}[d(C,Q)]+\mathbb{E}[d(Q,Y)]$$
In other words, you would get an additional term $\mathbb{E}[\phi(Y,Y)]$ for those proper scoring rules that don't obey $\phi(e_i,e_i)=0$.

You could also change the proper scoring rule $\phi$ itself. The rule $\phi'$ defined as $\phi'(p,y)=\phi(p,y)-\phi(y,y)$ is proper as well and obeys $\phi'(e_i,e_i)=0$. For example, the following (modified?) spherical rule $\phi_{\mathsf{spherical}}$ obeys $\phi_{\mathsf{spherical}}(e_i,e_i)=0$:
$$\phi_{\mathsf{spherical}}(p,y)=1-\frac{p_y}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{k} p_j^2}}$$
where $p_y$ denotes the component $p_i$ such that $y_i=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and complementary arguments. That was insightful!